# Am i missing how the graph api works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using [this gem](http://github.com/chrisdinn/hyper-graph), which is just a wrapper for the facebook graph API. I trying trying to post something to the logged in users facebook wall. This task seems easy enough but i am having these problems

```
graph = HyperGraph.new("some token").get('me')
=> {:last_name=>"Jones", :updated_time=>Fri Aug 06 22:27:03 -0400 2010, :email=>"jones11@gmail.com", :locale=>"en_US", :link=>"http://www.facebook.com/matt.jones", :verified=>true, :first_name=>"Matt", :timezone=>-4, :name=>"Matt Jones", :birthday=>"04/22/1985", :id=>503888340}
graph.object('503888340').post(:comments, :message => 'durian is disgustingly delicious')

FacebookError: OAuthException - (#100) Invalid fbid.
```

How do i post a message to my wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing :comments with :feed